# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' - tried to add int to input no luck

Tags: python, typeerror

I have looked at a lot of these similar questions and I thought I used the information correct by adding int to my input but I am still receiving the same error. Can anyone help?

```
import random

class Cards:
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = 1
        
    def getRank(self):
        ranks = ["Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
                 "Seven", "Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack", "Queen", "King"]
        self.rank = random.choice(ranks)
        return self.rank

    def getSuit(self):
        suits = ["Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds"]
        self.suit = random.choice(suits)
        return self.suit

    def getValue(self):
        if self.rank >= 10:
            return self.rank
        else:
            return 10

    def __str__(self):
      return (self.rank, "of", self.suit)

def main():
    n = int(input("How many cards would you like to see? "))
    
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        ranks = ["Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
             "Seven", "Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack", "Queen", "King"]
        suits = ["Clubs", "Hearts", "Spades", "Diamonds"]
    
        cardhand = Cards(random.choice(ranks), random.choice(suits))
        print ("The", cardhand, "has a Blackjack value of", cardhand.getValue())
        

main()
```

Comment: This isn't due to what you are doing with the input, rather, it happens here: `self.rank >= 10:`. `self.rank` is going to be one of: `ranks = ["Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack", "Queen", "King"]`. All of those are strings, hence the error

Comment: Please post the traceback message so that we can easily spot the failing line.

Answer (score 0):

Your `rank` attribute is a string describing the card, not a numeric value. But in `getValue`, you compare `self.rank >= 10`. Since `self.rank` is a string, this is nonsensical. I'd suggest making `self.rank` numeric, and just having a function to convert from numeric value to string form for display.

I'll also note your `getRank` and `getValue` functions are nonsensical; you class instances represent a single card, and calling functions that appear to be logically "getters" (retrieving information *about* the card) actually *change* the cards rank and value permanently when called, ignoring the values the card was initialized with.